# Display bookings for first of every month

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I'm trying to display hotel bookings from the 1st of every month.

- Hotel (hotelNo,hotelName,hotelAddress)
- Room (hotelNo,roomNo,type,price)
- Guest (guestNo,guestName,guestAddress)
- Booking (hotelNo,guestNo,dateFrom,dateTo,roomNo)

Here's what I have so far.  Obviously it isn't working.  How do I select the first of any given month?

```
SELECT hotelNo, dateFrom
FROM booking
WHERE datefrom >= to_date('01', 'dd');
```

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE RESULT YOU WOULD EXPECT FROM YOUR QUERY.

Comment: You want bookings that are from the current month? or specifically bookings of the first day of the month?

Comment: @FilipeSilva I'm trying to list bookings that are from the first day of any month

Answer (score 3):

If you want records that are on the first day of any month, then you can `EXTRACT` the day part of the date and compare it with 1:

```
SELECT hotelNo, dateFrom
FROM booking
WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM datefrom) = 1;
```